# MvcSiteMapProvider - builder set registration using structuremap moved to a separate method?

Tags: structuremap, mvcsitemapprovider

I have an MVC app for which I am using MvcSiteMapProvider to display breadcrumbs. I have read through https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Sitemaps-in-One-Application and gotten multiple sitemaps to work correctly in my application. I'm using StructureMap as the DI container for MvcSiteMapProvider.

In the example above, two SiteMapBuilder class instances are manually created and then they are both injected into the SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy constructor together.

I have about a dozen sitemaps in use. This number my change in the future. In order to minimize the maintenance involved, I would like to create a method call that will handle properly injecting a SiteMapBuilder instance into the SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy constructor.

so I would like to go from something like this

```
//instance 1
var source1 = this.For<IXmlSource>()
            .Use<FileXmlSource>()
            .Ctor<string>"fileName").Is([filepath to sitemap file]));

var provider1 = this.For<ISiteMapNodeProvider>()
            .Use<XmlSiteMapNodeProvider>()
            .Ctor<bool>("includeRootNode").Is(true)
            .Ctor<bool>("useNestedDynamicNodeRecursion").Is(false)
            .Ctor<IXmlSource>().Is(source1);

var builder1 = this.For<ISiteMapBuilder>()
            .Use<SiteMapBuilder>()
            .Ctor<ISiteMapNodeProvider>().Is(provider1);

//instance 2
var source2 = this.For<IXmlSource>()
            .Use<FileXmlSource>()
            .Ctor<string>("fileName").Is([filepath to sitemap file]));

var provider2 = this.For<ISiteMapNodeProvider>()
            .Use<XmlSiteMapNodeProvider>()
            .Ctor<bool>("includeRootNode").Is(true)
            .Ctor<bool>("useNestedDynamicNodeRecursion").Is(false)
            .Ctor<IXmlSource>().Is(source2);

var builder1 = this.For<ISiteMapBuilder>()
            .Use<SiteMapBuilder>()
            .Ctor<ISiteMapNodeProvider>().Is(provider2);

//inject
this.For<ISiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>()
            .Use<SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>()
            .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapBuilderSet>()
            .Contains(x =>
            {
                x.Type<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                   .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is("instance 1")
                   .Ctor<bool>("securityTrimmingEnabled").Is(true)
                   .Ctor<bool>("enableLocalization").Is(false)
                   .Ctor<ISiteMapBuilder>().Is(builder1)
                   ;
               x.Type<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                   .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is("instance 2")
                   .Ctor<bool>("securityTrimmingEnabled").Is(true)
                   .Ctor<bool>("enableLocalization").Is(false)
                   .Ctor<ISiteMapBuilder>().Is(builder2)
                   ;
            });
```

to something like this, that I would be able to call from the Registry constructor.

```
methodized(string filePath, string instanceName)
    {
        var source = this.For<IXmlSource>().Add<FileXmlSource>()
            .Ctor<string>("fileName").Is(filePath);
        var provider = this.For<ISiteMapNodeProvider>()
            .Add<XmlSiteMapNodeProvider>()
            .Ctor<bool>("includeRootNode").Is(true)
            .Ctor<bool>("useNestedDynamicNodeRecursion").Is(false)
            .Ctor<IXmlSource>().Is(source);
        var builder = this.For<ISiteMapBuilder>().Add<SiteMapBuilder>()
            .Ctor<ISiteMapNodeProvider>().Is(provider);


        this.For<ISiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>().Add<SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>()
            .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapBuilderSet>().Contains(x =>
            {
                x.Type<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                   .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is(instanceName)
                   .Ctor<bool>("securityTrimmingEnabled").Is(true)
                   .Ctor<bool>("enableLocalization").Is(false)
                   .Ctor<ISiteMapBuilder>().Is(builder)
                   ;
            });
    }
```

I'm not familiar with StructureMap, nor am I having much luck creating said method. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I have about a dozen sitemaps in use." Sounds like it could be overkill. There are usually better performing options than creating multiple SiteMaps. Unless you have multiple tenants or have some other need to keep them separate, the recommended way is to load all of the nodes that you need into the same SiteMap and use Security Trimming, Visibility Providers, Custom HTML helper templates, and/or Custom HTML helpers to control which nodes are displayed.

Comment: Noted. It very well may be overkill, but is a part of the landscape I must work with nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution. Instead of methodizing everything, I created a method that created the SiteMapBuilder, and added it to a collection.

I called this method the dozen or so times for all my sitemaps, and then looped through the collection within the SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy injection.

It seems to work - though if there are better approaches please feel free to comment.